# how to detect if user navigates from my website to another one or just simply refreshes it

Tags: javascript, web

I want to call my function when user navigates to other website - from mine (not to mine). I tried using

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    //logic here
};
```

But the problem is this also gets called when user refreshes the page which I don't want.

Any graceful way you can think of or anything ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

    <a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Link2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Link3</a>
       <script>
      let linkList = document.querySelectorAll('a')
      for (let elem of linkList){
        elem.onclick = e => window.confirm('OK?')
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

In this way you can prevent navigate from your site.
If you want to detect or your page is inactive(user now at another page, but 
yours still alive) you can use `window.onfocus`